# CakePHP 2 : Implement CakePDF plugin by Ceeram

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.x

I'm trying to implement the CakePDF plugin designed by Ceeram.

I'm using CakePHP 2 and I work locally using wamp on windows vista. I followed everything from the readme file but I got stucked at some point.

What I'd firstly like to do is converting an HTML link to a PDF using the WkHtmlToPdf engine. I see many people having issues to make it work so I'm gonna detail all the way through in the following different steps.

---

### STEP 1: CakePdf plugin by Ceeram

I downloaded the plugin at https://github.com/ceeram/CakePdf
I extracted the contained folder into app/Plugin/CakePdf

---

### STEP 2: Bootstrap

I added the following lines - app/Config/bootstrap.php :

```
CakePlugin::load('CakePdf', array('bootstrap' => true, 'routes' => true));

Configure::write('CakePdf', array(
    'engine' => 'CakePdf.WkHtmlToPdf'
    ),
    'orientation' => 'portrait',
    'download' => true
));
```

---

### STEP 3: Controller

I've created my controller "InvoicesController.php" - app/Controller/InvoicesController.php:

class InvoicesController extends AppController {

```
    public $components = array('RequestHandler');

    public function view($id = null) {

        $this->Invoice->id = $id;

        if (!$this->Invoice->exists()) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid invoice'));
        }

        $this->pdfConfig = array(
            'orientation' => 'portrait',
            'filename' => 'Invoice_' . $id
            );

        $this->set('invoice', $this->Invoice->read(null, $id));
    }
}
```

---

### STEP 4: View

I've created a pdf folder in my view folder and created view.ctp in app/View/Invoices/pdf/view.ctp.

---

### STEP 5: Layout

I've created a pdf folder in my layout folder and created app/View/Layouts/pdf/default.ctp

---

That's about it. In my view I couldn't make a PDF file from an URL.
Although I have to mention I'm new in OOP and CakePHP so I would be very grateful if you could show me how to have this done. I'm sure it will help others because there many newbies like me who want to do this but because it's all meant for advanced programmers we cannot figure out how to put the pieces together.

Thank you very much for your understanding and your help!

[THIS POST IS MODIFIED EACH TIME THERE IS A NEW ANSWER WHICH IMPROVES IT]

Comment: how are you accessing it? what is the exact url? also, what exactly is happening?

Comment: why did you rename it to CakePDF?? CakePdf is correct

Comment: @mark: I access with localhost/CakePHP/invoices/view/1.pdf and get a 500 error even if i try localhost/invoices/view/1.pdf using Router::mapResources(array('Invoices')); in the routes file located in config folder.
AT->Ceeram: I edited my original post to correct that mistake.

Comment: Contact the plugin author if the documentation is wrong.

Comment: @MartinBean He is already aware of this post, commented and answered as well

Comment: i am also facing problem with this plugin.. 

Missing View

Error: The view for InvoicesController::view() was not found.

Error: Confirm you have created the file: D:\wamp\www\sports\app\View\Invoices\view.ctp

Notice: If you want to customize this error message, create app\View\Errors\missing_view.ctp

Comment: i have follows all the steps

Comment: I am so done with cakephp. It's a great framework but there's too much chance to make an error in the code. It happens too often and sometimes I spend hours trying to locate it. So I moved to Wordpress which is much better for my needs and now I create custom themes. Much more fun and easier than cakephp.

Comment: Hello there! How do install wkhtmltopdf to make it work on my cakephp site? @Ceeram

Answer (score 1):

You need to add RequestHandler component, and browse to localhost/invoices/view/1.pdf

Looks like i had forgotten to mention to add RequestHandler component in the readme.

Also for WkHtmlToPdf you need to tell it where it can find it, and since you are on windows the default location surely wont work for you. You can set the location with Configure::write('CakePdf.binary', 'C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\wkhtmltopdf.exe') after having installed it on windows

Comment: Thanks Ceeram. I just edited my original post including "public $components = array('RequestHandler');" in my controller. About WkHtmlToPdf, how can I point it where it is? You mean it won't work at all on windows? Could you be more specific please, i'm very grateful that you bother to help, thanks for that! Anyway for now I'm getting a 500 error when I try to access to localhost/CakePHP/invoices/view/1.pdf even if i try localhost/invoices/view/1.pdf using Router::mapResources(array('Invoices'));

Comment: Router::mapResources(array('Invoices')); will make rest routes, so you would be able to access the same invoice at http://localhost/invoices/1.pdf instead. You can try with one if the included engines first. For wkhtmltopdf you need to install this, the readme has a link for this.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing  this code in app/config/routers.php

Router::parseExtensions();
Router::setExtensions(array('json', 'xml', 'rss', 'pdf'));

details available on:
http://www.dereuromark.de/2014/04/08/generating-pdfs-with-cakephp/