# ceeram/CakePdf plugin implement in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, pdf, cakephp-2.0, tcpdf

i have followed all the steps from https://github.com/ceeram/CakePdf
and [CakePHP 2 : Implement CakePDF plugin by Ceeram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14751428/cakephp-2-implement-cakepdf-plugin-by-ceeram)
But plugin is not working means no PDF is generating.

**Bootstrap**

/*CakePdf plugin settings*/

```
CakePlugin::load('CakePdf', array('bootstrap' => true, 'routes' => true));
Configure::write('CakePdf', array(
        'engine' => 'CakePdf.Tcpdf',
        'options' => array(
            'print-media-type' => false,
            'outline' => true,
            'dpi' => 96
        ),
        'margin' => array(
            'bottom' => 15,
            'left' => 50,
            'right' => 30,
            'top' => 45
        ),
        'orientation' => 'landscape',
        'download' => true
    ));
```

**Controller**

```
<?php
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
App::uses('CakePdf', 'CakePdf.Pdf');

    class InvoicesController extends AppController {
        public $components = array("RequestHandler");
        public function view($id = null) {
        $this->pdfConfig = array(
            'orientation' => 'portrait',
            'filename' => 'Invoice_' . $id
            );
        }
    }
?>
```

Created view.ctp in app/View/Invoices/pdf/view.ctp.

When i am accessing `http://localhost/ckp_sports/invoices/view/1.pdf`

**Error:**

```
Missing View

Error: The view for InvoicesController::view() was not found.

Error: Confirm you have created the file: D:\wamp\www\ckp_sports\app\View\Invoices\view.ctp

Notice: If you want to customize this error message, create app\View\Errors\missing_view.ctp
```

[image]

Comment: What's your CakePHP version?

Comment: CakePHP version 2.5.1

Comment: Try adding `$this->viewClass = 'CakePdf.PdfView'` to your action.